# Getting Select and Option value using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to create a form where I can upload an image and add a Name dropdown field with values coming from a table namely first name and last name using CONCAT to combine them into a complete name.

The dropdown field has the values coming from the table and works just fine.

My only problem is I can't get the value of the dropdown field to store into a variable so I can include it on the insert query.

I tried getting the value of the option tag through the post method by getting it from the select tag using the name property.

```php
<?php

include('adminheader.php');
include('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
    if (!$_POST['description']) {
        $error = "<p>Description field is required</p>";
    }
    $ownerselected = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['owner']);
    $ownerselected1 = "hello";
    $imagedescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);
    $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $query = "INSERT INTO images(name,description,ownerid,uploaderid) VALUES ('$file','$imagedescription','$ownerselected','$userLoggedIn')";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $notification = "Image successfully inserted " . $ownerselected1;

    }
}
?>

<br/><br/>
<div class="imagecontainer container">
    <div class="logincontainer">
        <div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
        <div id="error"><?php echo $notification; ?></div>
        <div style="width:500px;">
            <h3 align="center"><strong>Select an Image to upload</strong></h3>
            <br/>

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT CONCAT(fname,' ',lname)AS Name FROM person";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                ?>
                <br/>
                <div class="form-group"> <!--Start of image upload -->
                    <label for="image">Click Browse to locate image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/>  <!--end of image upload -->
                    <br/>

                    <div class="form-group"> <!--Start of image description -->
                        <label for="description">Image Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"
                               placeholder="Enter txt">
                    </div> <!--end of image description -->

                    <div class="form-group"><!--start of owner dropdown -->
                        <label for="owner">Image Owner</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="owner" name="owner">
                            <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row1['Name']; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $row1['Name']; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>    <!--end of owner dropdown -->
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <br/>
```

When I run the script, everything looks fine on the front end but when I perform the insert, only the image gets written on the table and imageowner column has no value. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should include the code where you do the insert.

Comment: Just to confirm... that select tag is inside a form tag with method="post", right?  It's not all trying to do this in the same page load?

Comment: `$_post['owner'];` should be `$_POST['owner']`. Variable names are case sensitive in PHP (including super globals). Your code should throw a notice: _"Undefined variable: _post"_ and set the variable `$imageowner` to NULL, which is probably why you're not getting the value.

Comment: Please add full code. Currently, the only problem is that you are trying to read the owner value and echo the select tag in the same script without checking if it form is submitted or not.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is $_POST['owner']; sorry for the careless typing.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron yes it is inside a form tag with method="post"